# google cloud Flask SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, peewee

I am developing a website to make my own portfolio. I wanted to switch to google cloud service. I got my app working and a database up. I am able to connect via ip but if a an other instance get's create the ip has to be whitelisted first.

SQLAlchemly url is what i saw was the anwser. But i want to keep working with peewee if possible.

Can someone explain to me why my code is not connect from the app engine to the cloud sql.

My code

```
    """Main script for the blog website."""
from flask import Flask
from peewee import *
from livereload import Server, shell
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES, configure_uploads
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user
from jinja2 import Environment
import os
from playhouse.db_url import connect
import pymysql

# db = connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', password='fakepassword')
# db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', password='fakepassword')
try:
    db = connect('sqlite:///root:fakepassword@/DATABASE?unix_socket=/cloudsql/austinbakkerblog:us-west1:database')
except Exception:
    print('did not connect to database')
# 'mysql+mysqldb://%s:%s@/blog?unix_socket=/cloudsql/%s'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=False)
DEBUG = app.debug


# db = MySQLDatabase('database')
# db.connect()

# db = connect('mysql://root:fakepassword@127.0.0.1:3306/database')
# db = connect('mysql://root:fakepassword@/DATABASE?unix_socket=/cloudsql/austinbakkerblog:us-west1:database')
# db = connect('mysql://root:fakepassword@/cloudsql/austinbakkerblog:us-west1:database')
# db = connect('mysql://root:fakepassword@cloudsql/austinbakkerblog:us-west1:database')
# print(db.connect())


login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'


photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, photos)

import models
from views import *


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        models.initialize()
        print('=' * 100)
        app.run()
```

If anyone is willing to help that would amazing, i spendt the last to day's trying to get it work but no success.

Comment: What your setup is about is not exactly clear but I assume you are attempting to set up a connection between your App Engine Instance and the CloudSQL instance. There are a number of ways to implement such connections, which include using the [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#granting-access), or by using a [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app?hl=en_US#dynamicIP). Have you tried these methods?

Comment: I tried both options but couldn't get it to work. I was wondering if you had a peewee example or could help me formulate it because i am having no success.  @oakinlaja

Comment: `db = MySQLDatabase('database', user='root', password='##############', host='35.233.225.232', port=3306)` I can use this to connect but then i have to whitelist the instance. I but that means my app won't scale good

Answer (score 1):

So after a few days of grinding i got it to work. Not sure exactly how but it

> app.yaml

```
works. runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3


env_variables:

    SQL_USER: root
    SQL_PASSWORD: test
    SQL_DATABASE: database
    INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: austinbakkerblog:europe-west2:mydatabase1


beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "austinbakkerblog:europe-west2:mydatabase1"

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
```

> app.py

```
"""Main script for the blog's website."""
from flask import Flask
from peewee import *
from livereload import Server, shell
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES, configure_uploads
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user
from jinja2 import Environment
import os
import pymysql


db = MySQLDatabase(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='test', unix_socket='/cloudsql/austinbakkerblog:europe-west2:mydatabase1', database='database')

print(db.connect())
print(db.close())
```

Comment: Glad to hear you're unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a connection URL, it might be easier to debug if you just setup the database connection directly.

For example,

```
db = MySQLDatabase('db_name', user='root', password='dbpassword',
                   host='googlecloud.whatever.com', port=31337)
```

Can you get `pymysql` to connect?

Comment: if i would do this i would still have to whitelist the ip that it is comming from, don't i ?

Comment: `db = MySQLDatabase('database', user='root', password='##############', host='35.233.225.232', port=3306)` I got that to work. But the problem is not i have to whitelist every instance on my sql.

Comment: Presumably you would have to whitelist them regardless of what client library you're using, though? i.e., a connection is a connection, whether peewee, sqlalchemy, jdbc...?

Comment: On google cloud service all google app engines have access to it without whitelisting. So if i sure a ip im am rerouting the connection while that is not needed.